# parse HTML Table and format out text

Tags: php, bash, shell, parsing

Hello I have these isolated html codes (as my inputs):

Case1:

```
<td class="C" width="10%">
    <a href="URL1" onclick="ValDobleSubmit()">
  String1
         <span style="color: blue; font-weight:bold;">
           String2
        </span>
    </a>
</td>
<td class="C" width="15%">
    String3
</td>
<td class="t" align="left" width="15%">
    String4
</td>
<td class="t" align="left" width="10%">
    String5
</td>
```

Case 2

```
<td class="C" width="10%">
    <a href="URL1" onclick="ValDobleSubmit()">
  String1
    </a>
</td>
<td class="C" width="15%">
    String3
</td>
<td class="t" align="left" width="15%">
    String4
</td>
<td class="t" align="left" width="10%">
    String5
</td>
```

I would like to use bash shells scripts or PHP (console) in order to have this output:

- case1:

String1String2|URL1|String3|String4|String5

- case2:

String1|URL1|String3|String4|String5

Comment: Please post some code which you wrote that proves your effort to solve this. Also see what makes an [mcve]

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention my effort.

My input is in a file.txt so I tried this for case1:
cat file.txt |grep -v "<" |while read a ; do echo $a"|"; done|sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'|sed 's/|*$//g

I can get this:

String1| String2| String3| String4| String5

Comment: I have a basic solution using this, but the problem is when my input file came with several cases together in the same file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     $DOM = new DOMDocument;
     $DOM->loadHTML($CaseSource);
     $cells = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('td');
    foreach($cells as $cell){
$out[] = $cell->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: also can use strip_tags(); to escape html tags